# Why does this Color.HSVToColor method return this strange value (with a negative sign)?

Tags: android, colors, hsv, color-space, android-color

This is an SSCCE to demonstrate that the `HSV` color `{11.0f, 9.0f, 215f}` when checked [here](http://colorizer.org/) is whitish (although the value of `V` or `Value`, `215`, automatically changes to `100` on this tool), whereas when I apply android's `Color.HSVToColor(float [] f)` function is applied, it results in the value **`-53504`**, which looks dubious when I look at minus sign. Besides, its color turns out to be red.

**The question is why and how do I solve this?**

[image]

**MainActivity.java:**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    View view;
    TextView textView;
    float [] hsv = {11.0f, 9.0f, 215.0f};

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        view = findViewById(R.id.mainActivity_view);
        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mainActivity_textView);

        int androidColor = Color.HSVToColor(hsv);

        view.setBackgroundColor(androidColor);
        textView.setText(androidColor+"");
    }
}
```

***Activity_main.java:***

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="10dp" >

    <View android:id="@+id/mainActivity_view"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/mainActivity_textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="15dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Negative in decimal is perfectly reasonable. Exactly half of the colors will be negative, as Java does not have `unsigned int`. Use `Integer.toHexString()` and look at the color value in hex. Also, your values are out of range for [the documented values for `HSVToColor()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Color.html#HSVToColor%28float[]%29), as `9f` is not between 0 and 1, and `215f` is not between 0 and 1.

Comment: Your values seem to be off even for your website, since B must be between 1 and 100 on that site.  But even after that it needs to be normalized between 0 and 1.

Comment: @CommonsWare What should I do then? I was using OpenCV4Android, and found that HSV as the color of a colored blob in the camera frame. So can't do anything about those values.

Comment: @GabeSechan What should I do then? If you can name a topic, I will try to read up on it.

Comment: Ask the OpenCV4Android team, I guess, if they are the ones giving you those values. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV#From_HSV) agrees with the Android docs, that S and V range from 0 to 1.

Comment: There's 2 good guesses I can make-  that those weren't floats but were meant to be bytes, in which case dividing by 256 would give good values.  Or that they were meant to be between 1 and 100, so dividing by 100 would give good values.  Given it returned 216, I'd try the 256 solution first, then try 100.

Comment: You might find this reading interesting: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV

Comment: @GabeSechan The HSV returned by the OpenCV4Android library was a `double []` array. I converted it to `float []` array by something like `for (int i=0; i<doubleArray.length; i++) {
  floatArray[i] = (float) doubleArray(i);
}`. I logged out the values in the double array as well as the float array, and they were `11.0`, `9.0` and `215.0` in both the cases.

Comment: @GabeSechan Dividing all three values by 100 gives an almost-black color (the real color I captured in the frame was near-to-white) [here](colorizer.org). Also divided by 256 anyway, and got almost black color.

Comment: @FrankN.Stein Thank you very much. Actually today I am going to start with the very basics of color (as I think I only have a vague understanding) - then I'll read about color spaces and read this article.

Comment: You'll find it illuminating... ;)